# Vuejs find the indexof identifier array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I want to find the index of identifier and push an valid_value array. vut can find the indexof the array the value return indexof is -1

```
PoiDetails: {
      parent_entity_id: 0,
      display_name: '',
      event_code_prefix: '',
      address: '',
      logo: {
        logo_name: '',
        logo_content: ''
      },
      logo_url: '',
      is_active: true,
      identifier: []
    }
```

Inside identifier[] the code is

```
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
0:
entity_type_key: (...)
display_name: (...)
model_entity_id: (...)
is_active: (...)
is_mandatory: (...)
valid_value: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get entity_type_key: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set entity_type_key: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get display_name: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set display_name: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get model_entity_id: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set model_entity_id: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get is_active: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set is_active: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get is_mandatory: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set is_mandatory: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get valid_value: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set valid_value: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

Can i find the indexof identifier array

Comment: `indexOf` is for locating an item in an array. Your question sounds like you are trying to find the index of an array inside an object, which doesn't make sense. You access the array with `PoiDetails.identifier`.  The only use of `indexOf` that makes sense here is `PoiDetails.identifier.indexOf(item)`

Comment: PoiDetails.identifier.indexOf(item) i tried but not working for me

Comment: i solved it with PoiDetails.indexOf(item)

Comment: But `PoiDetails` is not an array so that's not possible..